# imacros javascript window.onload not working

Tags: javascript, dom, onload, imacros, onload-event

Ive ran my script a couple of times and cant figure out why the window.onload isnt working. What am I not doing right ?

```
 var macro = "CODE:";
 macro += "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + "\n";
 macro += "TAB T=1" + "\n";
 macro += "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + "\n";
 macro += "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP YES" + "\n";
 macro += "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 60" + "\n";
 macro += "SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 60" + "\n";
 macro += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
 macro += "SET !DATASOURCE C:\\imacros\\test.csv" + "\n";
 macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1" + "\n"
 macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1" + "\n";
 macro += "URL GOTO={{!COL1}}" + "\n";
 function addlisteners(){
 window.alert("Boo !");
 }
 window.onload = addlisteners;

 iimPlay(macro);
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you got?

Comment: Surprisingly, no error message  and the function doesnt run at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I am not sure what you tried to do with the script above but this code works fine.

    var macro = "CODE:";
    macro += "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + "\n";
    macro += "TAB T=1" + "\n";
    macro += "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + "\n";
    macro += "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP YES" + "\n";
    macro += "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 60" + "\n";
    macro += "SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 60" + "\n";
    macro += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
    macro += "SET !DATASOURCE C:\\imacros\\test.csv" + "\n";
    macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1" + "\n"
    macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1" + "\n";
    macro += "URL GOTO={{!COL1}}" + "\n";




    iimPlay(macro);

   addlisteners();


    function addlisteners() {
        alert("Boo !");
    }
```

How about now?

Comment: Nope, this one loads the alert before the page even loads. Im trying to get the alert after the page loads. Thats why I tried using the window.onload function.

Comment: In other words Im trying to get around an object undefined hence fire  a script only after the page {{!COL1}} loads.

Comment: Worked pretty well , going see how it would react when I put iimPlay and the function call in a loop. Thanks